# Retrieve Google user name from device

Tags: android

I have to retrieve Google username from the device without using the Google API.. I tried some of the codes on stack overflow, but it did not work..
Please help

Comment: You mean, Google Account email?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
public class UserEmailFetcher {

    static String getEmail(Context context) {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        Account account = getAccount(accountManager);

        if (account == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return account.name;
        }
    }

    private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        Account account;
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            account = accounts[0];
        } else {
            account = null;
        }
        return account;
    }

}
```

Add one permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Reference answer : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449534/1994950)